# How build sql query with many parameters from java code?

Tags: java, oracle

I have sql select with parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl t WHERE t.name = ? AND t.age = ? AND t.number = ? AND ... AND t.last_parameter = ? order by t.some desc //many parameterss
```

I get parameters from form's fields and some fields may be empty. I build sql string:

```
String sqlStatementText;
        MessageFormat sqlStatementTextTemplate = new MessageFormat(Queries.WAR_GET_REPORT_COUNT);
        List<Object> parametrs = new ArrayList<>();
        if (null == subscriberMSISDN || subscriberMSISDN.length() == 0) {
            parametrs.add("");
        } else {
            parametrs.add(Queries.WAR_REPORT_CALLING_NUMBER);
        }
        if (null == operatorID || operatorID.length() == 0) {
            parametrs.add("");
        } else {
            parametrs.add(Queries.WAR_REPORT_OPERATOR_AVAYA_ID);
        }
        if (null == operatorNickname || operatorNickname.length() == 0) {
            parametrs.add("");
        } else {
            parametrs.add(Queries.WAR_REPORT_NICKNAME);
        }
        if (null == msg1 || msg1.length() == 0) {
            parametrs.add("");
        } else {
            parametrs.add(Queries.WAR_REPORT_MSG1);
        }
        if (null == msg2 || msg2.length() == 0) {
            parametrs.add("");
        } else {
            parametrs.add(Queries.WAR_REPORT_MSG2);
        }
        sqlStatementText = sqlStatementTextTemplate.format(parametrs.toArray());
```

ant them i do it:

```
try (Connection sqlConnection = connectionPool.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement sqlStatment = sqlConnection.prepareStatement(sqlStatementText)) {
            int paramID = 1;
            sqlStatment.setInt(paramID++, 1);
            sqlStatment.setDate(paramID++, new java.sql.Date(fromDate.getTime()));
            sqlStatment.setDate(paramID++, new java.sql.Date(toDate.getTime()));
            if (null != subscriberMSISDN && subscriberMSISDN.length() != 0) {
                sqlStatment.setString(paramID++, subscriberMSISDN);
            }
            if (null != operatorID && operatorID.length() != 0) {
                sqlStatment.setString(paramID++, operatorID);
            }
            if (null != operatorNickname && operatorNickname.length() != 0) {
                sqlStatment.setString(paramID++, operatorNickname);
            }
            if (null != msg1 && msg1.length() != 0) {
                sqlStatment.setString(paramID++, msg1);
            }
            if (null != msg2 && msg2.length() != 0) {
                sqlStatment.setString(paramID++, msg2);
            }
            try (ResultSet resultSet = sqlStatment.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    count = resultSet.getInt(1);
                }
                resultSet.close();
                sqlStatment.close();
                sqlConnection.close();
            }
```

But i thig it not correctly. But I dont know how build sql query with many paramaters and if some parameters maybe empty.

Comment: can you make changes in your sqlStatementText? if yes one way to resolve the problem is use NVL in WHERE section... select * from ... WHERE 1=1 AND col1 = nvl(prm1, col1). in that case your existing approach should work with no changes

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to an ORM. They will have some form of [criteria](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html)-like object.
2. Use the param is null or column = param SQL syntax. `select x from y where (? is null OR column1 = ?)`
   You need to set the value of the param twice, and the input value can not legitimately be null.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it, given the SQL statement you have.

You need to change the SQL statement WHERE conditions from things like `t.name = ?` to  `t.name = nvl(?, t.name)`.  Then, you can bind a NULL there and the condition will always evaluate to `true` (so it's not acting as a filter -- which is what you want when the user leaves the field blank).

Or -- a better approach if you can do it, it's even better to use conditions like you've got them (e.g., `t.name= ?`), but build the conditions dynamically based on what fields the user give you.  That is, for example, if the user leaves the "name" parameter blank, just omit the `t.name = ?` condition entirely.

That leaves you with a shorter SQL statement that makes the Oracle optimizer's job a little bit easier.  With the `t.name = nvl(?, t.name)` approach I gave you above, you're relying on some pretty advanced optimizer features to get the best performance, because it's not immediately clear whether, say, it would be good or bad for the optimizer to use an index on `t.name`.